# Изменение поведения пассивного потока исполнения в std::call_once

Tags: c++, c++11

Как сделать так, чтобы два потока, пришедшие к точке `std::call_once` вели себя следующим образом: один из них (любой) начал бы активное исполнение функции в `call_once`, а другой вместо пассивного ожидания выполнил бы `abort()` или как-нибудь еще сломался?

Вопрос исходит из того, как сделать, чтобы в мультитреде обеспечить вызов к-ра некоторого класса только единожды. Пока идея такова, чтобы сделать в конструкторе вызов `std::call_once(flag, init)`, где `init()` - некая инициализирующая функция. А затем добавить в начало конструктора что-то типа `assert(called == 0)`. Возможно, я не прав, можно сделать проще однократный вызов?

Comment: Синглтон Майерса?

Comment: @Croessmah синглтон, но не Майерса. В плане, я делаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну можно добавить флажек

```
::std::atomic<bool> s_constructor_called{false};
```

...

```
if(!::std::atomic_exchange(::std::addressof(s_constructor_called), true))
{
   ::std::cout << "first attempt should succeed" << ::std::endl;
}
else
{
   ::std::cout << "second attempt should fail" << ::std::endl;
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Только вот `exit()` завершит все потоки